# Remove bottom and right borders (gaps) and customize scrollbar in Athena GVim

Tags: gvim, color

I found many webpages [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763539/how-to-remove-white-border-in-gvim-8-with-gtk-3)][[2](https://thomashunter.name/posts/2019-01-20-removing-gvim-border)][[3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47831/how-to-remove-gvims-fat-bottom-border-and-resize-grip)] explaining how to color the
gaps from [GTK GVim](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim-gtk3), but how can I do the same for [Athena GVim](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vim-athena)? In the left picture, gap should also be black, not gray.
What about the scrollbar frame, which does not blend well with a dark
background (right picture)?

[image: Shows window gap (bad!)]
[image: Bright scrollbar frame (bad!)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The scrollbar frame color is defined by the *topShadowPixel* and
   *bottomShadowPixel* X-resources.
2. The internal border (gap) of the window inherits its color from the scrollbar
   trough color, *scrollBackground*.

Those values can be modified by editing the `~/.Xresources` file (lines
starting with `!` are comments):

```
! Width of the scrollbar frame
Vim*scrollBar.shadowWidth:       1
! Background of the scrollbar's trough and color of Gvim's internal border
Vim.scrollBackground:            black
! Color of the scrollbar's slider
Vim.scrollForeground             blue
! Color of the scrollbar frame
Vim*scrollBar.topShadowPixel:    navyblue 
Vim*scrollBar.bottomShadowPixel: navyblue 
! Separation between scrollbar and Gvim's text
Vim.borderWidth:                 2
```

Issue `xrdb ~/.Xresources` and open a new Gvim, which will look
much better:

[image: Dark scrollbar frame (good!)]

Note that the scrollbar trough color (and thus the window internal border)
can be overriden by the *Scrollbar* highlight group:

```
:hi Scrollbar guibg=black
```

I collected that information from `:h gui-resources` and by digging the
window resources with [Editres](http://xfree86.org/current/editres.1.html).